# (Java) Converting a Quaternion into Radians (Or Degrees)?

Tags: java, opengl, quaternions, bulletphysics, radians

I've been messing around in OpenGL, and JBullet for the last few days. After a lot of tinkering I finally managed to fix quite a few bugs in JBullet, and make it usable for some demos. Issue I'm currently having is I can't manage to convert the translation into Degrees, so far I've had the best results with Quaternions, to Radians with the following code:

```
public Vector3f getRadians(Quat4f quat) {
    Vector3f v = new Vector3f();
    //float scale = (float) Math.abs(quat.x * quat.y * quat.z); //Apparently the scale of the angle, thought without I get a almost perfect result on the X-Axis
    float angle = (float) Math.abs(Math.acos(quat.w)) * 2.0f;

    v.x = angle * Math.round(quat.x);
    v.y = angle * Math.round(quat.y);
    v.z = angle * Math.round(quat.z);               

    return v;
}
```

It's worth noting that my only success would be on the X-Axis of the Quaternion, and that's with no translation on any other axis. Not to mention it's off by anywhere from 0-6 Degrees.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you intend to do and what is the question...

Comment: So you get three angles in radians, and you want to convert each of them to degrees? Multiply each angle in radians by 180 / π to get the angle in degrees.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I intend to perform conversion on a Quaternion, into either Degrees, or Radians (Since the conversion between the two is fairly simple).

Comment: @Jesper Well sort of, I know how to perform that conversion, but I'm having an issue getting a reliable conversion from a Quaternion, to Radians.

Comment: What do you consider the meaning of a quaternion converted to radians?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Well, a Quaternion is a format for storing angles.. so conversion would be changing the format pragmatically, yes?

Comment: @Josh: No. You have to ask where is the *reference* angle and what degrees of freedom are you willing to throw away. Quaternion uses 4 parameters and it can represent a rotation of 2*acos(w) around the axis x,y,z. Radian is but a single value.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I see, would you be able to aid me here, I do thank you for clarifying.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure this is what you want, but from glm::gtx::quaternion :

```
inline valType roll
(
    detail::tquat<valType> const & q
)
{
    return atan2(valType(2) * (q.x * q.y + q.w * q.z), q.w * q.w + q.x * q.x - q.y * q.y - q.z * q.z);
}

template <typename valType> 
inline valType pitch
(
    detail::tquat<valType> const & q
)
{
    return atan2(valType(2) * (q.y * q.z + q.w * q.x), q.w * q.w - q.x * q.x - q.y * q.y + q.z * q.z);
}

template <typename valType> 
inline valType yaw
(
    detail::tquat<valType> const & q
)
{
    return asin(valType(-2) * (q.x * q.z - q.w * q.y));
}
```

So, in a more readable form :

```
float roll = atan2(valType(2) * (q.x * q.y + q.w * q.z), q.w * q.w + q.x * q.x - q.y * q.y - q.z * q.z);
float pitch = atan2(valType(2) * (q.y * q.z + q.w * q.x), q.w * q.w - q.x * q.x - q.y * q.y + q.z * q.z);
float yaw = asin(valType(-2) * (q.x * q.z - q.w * q.y));
vec3 EulerAngles = vec3(pitch, yaw, roll);
```